# Search WordPress category for a tag

Tags: wordpress

I'm putting together a custom search that should search a specific category for a tag. So say the category options are toys, books and food and the tags are green, red or blue, a search goal would be to find green toys.

Right now I can pass the category green and the tag toys to wp but my results show all posts that are toys and all posts that include green.

Is it possible to search the category toy for green? or books for blue?

And how would i build that into a link? Or setup custom functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the category and tag parameters of wp_query, you should use the taxonomy parameters: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

eg,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'toys' ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'red' ),
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Hope that helps